# selenium webdriver can not find interactive web elements

Tags: python, selenium, automation

i am trying to automatically fill this form to download some documents from [this](http://rh.imss.gob.mx/tarjetonjubilados/(S(qe5sigjk52izptxehto533l2))/default.aspx) mexican government webpage for my family (they have to download them at least monthly) using selenium webdriver in python but it yields this error in all form elements:

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":
  (Session info: chrome=104.0.5112.81)
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
    Ordinal0 [0x00F85FD3+2187219]
    Ordinal0 [0x00F1E6D1+1763025]
    Ordinal0 [0x00E33E78+802424]
    Ordinal0 [0x00E61C10+990224]
    Ordinal0 [0x00E61EAB+990891]
    Ordinal0 [0x00E8EC92+1174674]
    Ordinal0 [0x00E7CBD4+1100756]
    Ordinal0 [0x00E8CFC2+1167298]
    Ordinal0 [0x00E7C9A6+1100198]
    Ordinal0 [0x00E56F80+946048]
    Ordinal0 [0x00E57E76+949878]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x012290C2+2721218]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x0121AAF0+2662384]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x0101137A+526458]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x01010416+522518]
    Ordinal0 [0x00F24EAB+1789611]
    Ordinal0 [0x00F297A8+1808296]
    Ordinal0 [0x00F29895+1808533]
    Ordinal0 [0x00F326C1+1844929]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x75806739+25]
    RtlGetFullPathName_UEx [0x772F8FEF+1215]
    RtlGetFullPathName_UEx [0x772F8FBD+1165]
```

i tried using ID, XPATH, full XPATH and CSS selector but none of them work. I also tried to check each element by themselves in a separate script and the result is the same.
this is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import re
import datetime
import time
today=today=datetime.date.today()
driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Users\HP\Downloads\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe")
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
for i in range(3):
    try:
        driver.get("http://rh.imss.gob.mx/tarjetonjubilados/(S(zh0qyvr1lwrxezeum4tjlypg))/default.aspx")
        break
    except:
        pass
#delchoice=driver.find_element(By.ID,"ddlDelegacion")
#delchoice.click()
delegacion=driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"/html/body/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[3]/select/option[37]")
delegacion.elect_by_index(integer redacted)
user=driver.find_element(By.ID,"txtUsuario")
user.send_keys(string redacted)
password=driver.find_element(By.ID,"txtContraseña")
password.send_keys(string redacted)
nextpage=driver.find_element(By.ID,"btnIngresar")
time.sleep(30)
for i in range(3):
    try:
        filebutton=driver.find_element(By.ID,"rdoArchivo")
        filebutton.click()
        break
    except:
        driver.navigate().refresh()
        time.sleep(30)
tarjetonbutton=driver.find_element(By.ID,"rdoTarjeton")
tarjetonbutton.click()
tarjetonchoicebutton=driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"/html/body/table/tbody/tr[6]/td/div/div[3]/div[3]/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[3]")
tarjetonchoicebutton.click()
tarjetondate=tarjetonchoicebutton.text
tarjetonredate=re.search(r"(?<=\d{2}\/)\d{2}(?=\/\d{4}\s\-)",tarjetondate)
tarjetonmonth=tarjetonredate.group
print(tarjetonmonth)
thismonth=str(today.month)
print(tarjetonmonth)
if thismonth==tarjetonmonth:
    downloadbutton=driver.find_element(By.ID,"btnAceptar")
    downloadbutton.click
driver.quit()
```

Another curious issue is that it do work with other page elements, just not the form ones

Comment: At which line are you stuck exactly?

Comment: at line 21 it throws that error code but it does the same in all the other lines with `find_element` too

Comment: Which line of code is _`line 21`_?

Comment: @undetectedSelenium this one `delegacion=driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"/html/body/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[3]/select/option[37]")` but again, all the `find_element` throw the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that all the form is inside an `iframe` which means you need to [actually switch to it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73326253/how-to-interact-with-interactive-elements-inside-iframe-using-selenium/73326515#73326515) before searching for the elements (actually the same will be needed for the next page).
This approach by @undetected Selenium works pretty well:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@id='ifrPaginaSecundaria']")))
Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//select[@id='ddlDelegacion']")))).select_by_index(INTEGER EXPUNGED)
```

although it requires the following imports:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
```

with all of that the full code ends up like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import re
import datetime
import time
today=today=datetime.date.today()
driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Users\HP\Downloads\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe")
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
for i in range(3):
    try:
        driver.get("http://rh.imss.gob.mx/tarjetonjubilados/(S(zh0qyvr1lwrxezeum4tjlypg))/default.aspx")
        break
    except:
        driver.navigate().refresh()
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@id='ifrPaginaSecundaria']")))
Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//select[@id='ddlDelegacion']")))).select_by_index(INTEGER EXPUNGED)
user=driver.find_element(By.ID,"txtUsuario")
user.send_keys(STRING EXPUNGED)
password=driver.find_element(By.ID,"txtContraseña")
password.send_keys(STRING EXPUNGED)
nextpage=driver.find_element(By.ID,"btnIngresar")
nextpage.click()
time.sleep(10)
for i in range(3):
    try:
        driver.switch_to.default_content()
        WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@id='ifrPaginaSecundaria']")))
        filebutton=driver.find_element(By.ID,"rdoArchivo")
        filebutton.click()
        break
    except:
        driver.navigate().refresh()
        time.sleep(5)
tarjetonbutton=driver.find_element(By.ID,"rdoTarjeton")
tarjetonbutton.click()
tarjetonchoicebutton=driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"/html/body/table/tbody/tr[6]/td/div/div[3]/div[3]/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[3]")
tarjetonchoicebutton.click()
tarjetondate=tarjetonchoicebutton.text
tarjetonredate=re.search(r"(?<=\d{2}\/)\d{2}(?=\/\d{4}\s\-)",tarjetondate)
tarjetonmonth=int(tarjetonredate.group())
thismonth=int(today.month)
if thismonth==tarjetonmonth:
    print("download cleared")
    downloadbutton=driver.find_element(By.ID,"btnAceptar")
    downloadbutton.click()
```